# Wait for a Redux action to return a value from API and based on the response need to navigate to Screen

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am developing a simple signUp screen using react native. If the user enter all data (first name, last name, email) in the form, the entered data will get passed to the API and saved it to DB.I have a simple validation here ..i.e.. Once user submits I am dispatching the action to call API and the API will return true if the user entered email is already existing.
Based on the return result from the API, I need to proceed further.
if true (email already existing) I need to show some error message.
if false(email not existing) I need to navigate to next screen.
My Problem is while dispatching action it is not waiting for return value. 
Below I have mention my code,
once submitted calling the js function to dispatch action,
[image]
My redux action
[image]
My log
[image]

Comment: Taking a quick look at this, it seems that you're trying to return resData in that .finally but I don't think .finally is in the same scope as resData. Can you provide a link to your repo?

Comment: https://github.com/bharath2069/ReactNative here it is